# Preview Link Inside Post Body Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I planned on embedding URLs into a post body when the post is been created and also would like if the automatically preview  details inside the post body after it has been submitted, URLs like YouTube , Twitter, Instagram I would like to automatically display there details inside a post body

please how can I do this?

using this package
https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed

```
preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $post->body, $urls);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to do this process before passing the post body to the view also specify a section to show your data, like so

**Your PHP Code**

```
public function show (Post $post)
{
    // Your pattern to find the URL that you want
    $isMatch = preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $post->body, 'matches_urls');
    $urlDetails = [];

    foreach ($urlsThatYouFind as $url)
    {
       $embed = new Embed();

       // Load any url
       $info = $embed->get($url);
       $urlDetails['info'] = $info;

       // Get content info
       $urlDetails['title'] = $info->title;  //The page title
    }

    return view('post.view', compact('post', 'urlDetails'));
}
```

**Your view**

```
<p>{{ $post->body }}</p>

<div>{{ $urlDetails['title'] }}</div>
```